# How to skip certain input from a text file

Tags: java, file-io, filter

I am trying to take in a file that looks like the following (but with hundreds of more lines):

```
  123 000 words with spaces 123 123 123 words with spaces
  123 000 and again words here 123 123 123 and words again
```

The 123, 000, "words with spaces" stuff are different each line. I am just trying to show it as a placeholder for what I need.

If I only need to get the 123's of each row, how can I ignore the other stuff in there?

Below is what I have tried:

```
  File file = new File("txt file here"); 
   try (Scanner in = new Scanner(file))
     {
         int count = 0;
         while (in.hasNext())
         {
             int a = in.nextInt();
             String trash1 = in.next();
             String trash2 = in.next();
             String trash3 = in.next();
             int b = in.nextInt();
             int c = in.nextInt();
             int d = in.nextInt();
             //This continues but I realize this will eventually throw an
             //exception at some points in the text file because 
             //some rows will have more "words with spaces" than others
         }
     }
     catch (FileNotFoundException fnf)
     {
         System.out.println(fnf.getMessage());
     }
```

Is there a way to skip the "000's" and the "words with spaces" stuff that way I only take in the "123's"? Or am I just approaching this in a "bad" way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab line by line and split the line around a space and iterate over the array of strings only caring if the string in the array matches what you want

```
int countsOf123s = 0;
while (in.hasNextLine())
{
    String[] words = in.nextLine().split(" "); //or for any whitespace do \\s+
    for(String singleWord : words)
    {
        if(singleWord.equals("123"))
        {
            //do something
            countsOf123s++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions to strip the first part of the line.

```
String cleaned = in.nextLine().replace("^(\\d+\\s+)+([a-zA-Z]+\\s+)+", "");
```

`^` means the pattern starts at the beginning of the text (the start of the line)

`(\\d+\\s+)+` matches one or more groups of digits followed by whitespace.

`([a-zA-Z]+\\s+)+` matches one or more groups of alphabetic characters followed by whitespace.

You may have to modify the pattern if there's punctuation or other characters. You can read more about regular expressions [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) if you're new to using them.